# Implementing shortcuts (reach) pruning while using A*

Tags: algorithm, mapping, openstreetmap, graph-theory, a-star

I am working on a project for shortest path finding. I have looked at alot of resources online to come up with a good algorithm.

I am working with openstreetmap data and it's clear to me that I have to use A* algorithm.

While looking for different solutions, I have found that because a way is made of different nodes, one can prune away the intermediate nodes that are not junctions. 
How can I do this in a programming language? If anyone has an idea or a further article that can help me, that would be really grateful.

The exact information I found about this pruning that's relevant to osm is this

> parse all ways a second time; a way will normally become one edge,
>   but if any nodes apart from the first and the last have a link counter
>   greater than one, then split the way into two edges at that point.
>   Nodes with a link counter of one and which are neither first nor last
>   can be thrown away unless you need to compute the length of the edge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look into the [GraphHopper project](https://graphhopper.com/) (where I'm the author of) or other [routing projects for OSM](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing) already doing this. The idea is to count the number of ways one node is member of and mark nodes as junctions if they have a count of three or more (or just one if an endstanding 'junction').

Still the nodes in-between should be accessible as you need to plot the route for the end results after calculating the route. In GraphHopper we call them pillar nodes (nodes between junctions) and tower nodes (junctions). [Here](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/blob/master/docs/core/low-level-api.md#what-are-pillar-and-tower-nodes) is more detailed information.

Another problem is that you have to calculate GPS precise routes and not just routes from junction to junction. Look into [this change](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/pull/115) how we fixed this via virtual nodes and edges.

Comment: is there source code available for how you did the data parsing and create the graph so that only the tower nodes are included in the graph while traversing it? EDIT: or to how avoid those pillar nodes while doing the traversal

Comment: Yes, sure it is all open source. See OSMReader. But this part is the simplest compared to the other problems you then have ;)